# Why is careers.stackoverflow.com forcing me to widen my browser window?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, design, horizontal-scroll-bar

Why is careers.stackoverflow.com forcing me to widen my browser window?

I don't like my browser full width. I don't want to be forced to widen my browser window or scroll to get at other parts of the interface.

This is what careers looks like in my browser. Cramped is too kind a description.

[image]

To give you an idea of what is hidden:

[image]

"For employers" may not be what I am interested in, but the login link is on that site too, as well as the "invitations".

Truly sorry to see this on the stack stack. Especially as you do know how to get it right. Stackoverflow itself doesn't force a minimum fixed width on me. It displays the entire network header and does not produce a horizontal scrollbar...

I posted this as a bug, because I truly consider it a bug in the user experience provided.

Edit:

For all the upvoters of the "Press Ctrl-0" comment: don't you think there might be a good reason for the browser being zoomed in? It should not matter. SO itself responds correctly when narrowing the window, regardless of zoom.

Comment: Uhm...press `Ctrl + 0`? I think you're just zoomed in.

Comment: @stealthyninja no, this is not a matter of zooming in. The page has a min width of something like 1000 px and when the window is narrower, the rightmost pixels are hidden.

Comment: @stealthyninja the screenshots may be confusing you (they did me). There are **two**; the second is scaled up to better illustrate what content is falling off the right hand side.

Comment: @stealthyninja is correct. The browser is zoomed in. This is evident by the magnifying glass icon in the address bar. See http://i.imgur.com/7BxP8aR.png .

Comment: Yes the browser is zoomed in. It also was zoomed in a couple of months ago. Then it did not cramp the information and cut off the right hand side forcing me to scroll. Besides, whether everything else (eg SO itself) responds pretty correctly when narrowing the window regardless of zoom.